# How to extract links from a web content?

Tags: java, regex

I have download a web page and I want to extract all the links in that file. this links include absolutes and relatives. for example we have :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" />
```

so after reading the file, what should I do?

Comment: Do you mean URLs? `<script>` is not a link.

Comment: absolutely. all the things that may cause a network request.

Comment: But then it would need to distinguish between URL and MIME type as well…

Comment: here we go, I have to agree. any solutions?

Comment: Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: I think you can adapt this: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Answer (score 0):

This isn't that complicated to do, if you want to use the builtin regex system from Java. The hard bit is finding the right regex to match URLs<sup>[1][2]</sup>. For the sake of the answer, I'm gonna just assume you've done that, and stored that as a `Pattern` with syntax along the lines of this:

```
Pattern url = Pattern.compile("your regex here");
```

and some way of iterating through each line. What you'll want to do is define an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
ArrayList<String> urlsFound = new ArrayList<>();
```

From there, you'll have some loop to iterate through your file (assuming each line is a `<? extends CharSequence> line`), and inside you'll put this:

```
Matcher urlMatch = url.matcher(line);
while (urlMatch.find()) urlsFound.add(urlMatch.match());
```

What this does is create a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for your line and the URL-matching `Pattern` from before. Then, it loops until [`#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) returns false (i.e., there are no more matches) and adds the match (with [`#group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--)) to the list, `urlsFound`.

At the end of your loop, `urlsFound` will contain all the matches for all of the URLs on the page. Note that this can get quite memory-intensive if you've got a lot of text, as `urlsFound` will get quite big, and you'll be creating and ditching a lot of `Matcher`s.

<sup>1: I found a few good sites with [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+to+match+URLs&oq=regex+to+match+URLs); the cream of the crop seem to be [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) and [here](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611), as far as I can tell. Your needs may vary.</sup>

<sup>2: You'll need to make sure that the entire URL is captured with a single group, or this won't work at all. It can be tweaked to work if there are multiple parts, though.</sup>